# Comma after "here"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, questions

I've been speculating whether or not I can use a comma after "here"? Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any clarifying answers anywhere, or perhaps I haven't been searching enough.

To the topic at hand, I have this profile and I wish to clarify something specific. In my introduction I've written:

> Here, I post whatever I please.

I wish to add emphasis, explaining the comma. Also, I wish to separate the location from the content.

Am I wrong or is it right? I really want to know.

Comment: Why do you think the sentence might not work? Do you have any other examples you're not sure about?

Comment: @Dodecaphone I tend to worry a lot, and suddenly a thought told me that I might be wrong. Searched and searched, but nothing answered my question. Decided to post here, since I reckon you're smarter than me.
I have no other examples. Just this one :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct to use a comma, but, at the same time, a comma is not necessary. It is a matter of preference.

"Here" is your sentence is what's sometimes called a disjunct adverb, because it does not fit *neatly* within the flow of  sentence (the italic *neatly*, on the other hand, does fit within the flow of the sentence, and is called an adjunct adverb). It modifies not a single verb or adjective, but an entire sentence. Very often, disjunct adverbs like yours are set off with a comma, so your use of a comma there is very common practice.

At the same time, many people believe that very short introductory adverbs or adverbial phrases do not require the comma:

With concise phrases, the comma may be omitted. You can as often see

*Today I got married.*

as

*Today, I got married.*

Deciding whether to use a comma or not can depend on what you want to emphasize--in this case, whether it's that you got married, which happened today, or what you did today, which is get married.

In your sentence, IMO, using the comma does add some emphasis to *here*, suggesting that on some other sites, you do not post what you like. But this is subtle, and the nuance may be lost on readers without more context. It is quite possible that some would assign this same meaning to your sentence even without the comma.

In short, this is a matter of personal style. If you have a real reason to include a comma, which seems to be the case, then include it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Indeed, on some other site I do not post whatever I please, and these two are somewhat connected. I see how it would be lost on some readers.

Comment: Forgot to add, that it all made perfect sense. You're truly intelligent! Thanks, good sir or miss ;)

Comment: Thank you. Many of my colleagues would say I know a little bit about grammar, but "truly intelligent" might find some argument. You're very gracious.

Comment: You're much smarter than me, so that's why. Also, if I compared you the majority, then you're definitely intelligent.